# Build error deploying javafx application when added jna 4.1.0 library

Tags: deployment, javafx, jna

I am trying to build my app, but I have the next error.

**The jar libs\jna-4.1.0.jar has a main class com.sun.jna.Native that does not match the declared main com.bp.ocr.MainApp**

I do not know how to solve it, I am looking for but I am not understand why happens.

```
Using base JDK at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre 
The jar libs\jna-4.1.0.jar has a main class com.sun.jna.Native that 
  does not match the declared main com.bp.ocr.MainApp 
Bundler EXE Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: 
  Main application jar is missing.   
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar. 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```